# Line number of the caller of a preloaded library function

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld, dlsym

Let's say I have a program (program.c) that uses rand function in standard C library.

```
1 #include <stdlib.h>
2 int main(){
3     int rand_number = rand();
4 }
```

I also have a shared library (intercept.c) that I created to change the behaviour of rand function (simply adds +1 to the result) in the standard library.

```
int rand(void){
    int (*rand_func)();
    rand_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "rand");
    int result = (*rand_func)();
    return result + 1;
}
```

And I run the program with

```
LD_PRELOAD=./intercept.so ./program
```

Is there any way to get the line number (Line 3) and name of the caller function (main) without modifying the program.c's source code?

Comment: The C standard does not provide any facility for this. If the program is compiled with debugging information, it may be possible to get this information from it. That is somewhat complicated and is unlikely to be worth the effort required.

Comment: before using `rand()`, use something to seed the random number generator, similar to: `#include <time.h>` and  `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL) );`

Comment: @user3629249 Fully functioning rand function is not important in this context. I put it just to be an example.

Answer (score 3):

It is not immediate, but you can use [`backtrace()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) in order to obtain each frame in the call stack.
Then invoking the external command `eu-addr2line -f -C -s --pretty-print -p your_pid the_previous_frames...` (with `popen()` or `pipe()/fork()/dup2()/exec()...`) and parsing its output will provide the information you need
(if compiled with `-g`).

Comment: I don't have any control over the program.c. So, I don't know whether it was compiled with -g or not.

Comment: @M.Soyturk And with the binary obtained from `program.c` *as is*, did you try this approach? Of course `backtrace()` must be used in *your* code (`intercept.c`) and maybe `eu-addr2line` will give you something if the debug information are present *by chance* in the original program. By the way, what is the point of obtaining a call-stack and line numbers for a code you have no control over?

Comment: I did but I was not able to get the line number. I am trying to develop a collective communication profiling tool and I thought that showing the line number and stacktrace would be a good addition for productivity. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

*Is there any way to get the line number (Line 3) and name of the caller function (main) without modifying the program.c's source code?*

compile the program with the `-ggdb3` option,  Then set a break point where you want to stop the program.  Then use the backtrace command `bt`.   This will show the function names, the line numbers, etc

Comment: I don't have any control over the program.c. So, I don't know which flags were used while compiling program.c

Answer (score 0):

Another (Linux specific) approach is to compile everything with `-g` (perhaps also `-O`) using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and to use Ian Taylor's excellent [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace).

That library parses the [DWARF](http://www.dwarfstd.org/) debug information and knows line numbers.

You'll need several hours to understand `libbacktrace` (read carefully the header file). I am using it in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)

Comment: I have no control over the compilation of program.c. Therefore, I don't know which flags were used while compiling program.c. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Discuss with the human being providing  `program.o`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that luxury at this point. Thanks for the help.